# How do I make my program count the number of sentences starting with a capital letter in a string?

Tags: java

My program currently only counts the number of capital letters in the whole string, not the ones after a period mark.

Desired output:

Enter essay:

I like Cats. Hey.

Sentences starting with capital letter: 2

Current output:

---

Enter essay:

I like Cats. Hey.

Sentences starting with capital letter: 3

---

Here's my code so far:

```
 static int sentencesChecker(String shortEssay) {



    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < shortEssay.length(); i++) {

        if (isUpperCase(shortEssay.charAt(i))       ) {

           count++;

        }


    } System.out.println("Sentences starting with capital letter: " + count);

    return count;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter essay: ");
    String essay = input.nextLine();

    sentencesChecker(essay);
}
```

Comment: you need to seperate with whitespace (blank) and then check each characters uppercase what have you done

Comment: You're not counting the capital letters at the _start_ of a sentence but all, i.e. you iterate over all characters and check them for being upper case. However, you need to iterate over sentences and check the first character only, e.g. by splitting the input on sentence ending characters (`.!?`).

Comment: `return Arrays.stream(shortEssay.split("\\.")).map(String::trim).map(s -> s.charAt(0)).filter(Character::isUpperCase).count();`

Comment: Not sure why you got those downvotes; but for the next time: spent a bit more time on formatting your input. You want us to spend our time to help you; so you please spend the 5 seconds it takes to remove all those useless empty lines from your source code.

Answer (score 3):

Some more easy way than counting over the `char` array of the `String` would probably be the usage of `String#split`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter essay: ");
    String essay = input.nextLine();
    String[] Uppcasesentences = essay.split("\\.\\s*[A-Z]");
    if(Uppcasesentences[0].matches("^\\s*[A-Z].*")) {
        System.out.println("You have got " + essay.split("\\.\\s*[A-Z]").length + " sentences starting uppercase");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You have got " + (essay.split("\\.\\s*[A-Z]").length-1) + " sentences starting uppercase");
    }
}
```

O/P

```
Enter essay: 
Sentence 1. sentence 2. Sentence 3. Sentence 4. sentence 5. Sentence 6
You have got 4 sentences starting uppercase
```

What is happening here is, the `regex` splits the `String` on each occasion of a dot followed by 0-n whitespaces followed by an uppercase letter. The length of the array you did just created should equal the amount of sentences starting uppercase now.

Edit: the split did ignore the first sentence, and would produce `2` for the input `sentence 2. Sentence 2`. Checking if the first array element starts with uppercase now. If not subtract 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> A regular expression, regex or regexp (sometimes called a rational expression)
>    is, in theoretical computer science and formal language theory, a sequence of characters that define a search pattern. **Usually this pattern is then used by string searching algorithms for "find"** or "find and replace" **operations on strings**.

The regular expression to use in this context is:

```
^[A-Z]|\. *[A-Z]
```

That regular expression means (underlined the portion described in the right):

```
^[A-Z]|\. *[A-Z] Any uppercase letter from A to Z at the starting of line
------

^[A-Z]|\. *[A-Z]   or
      -

^[A-Z]|\. *[A-Z]   The character . followed by any number of 
       ---------   spaces, followed by an uppercase letter in the range A to Z
```

This can be used as follow in java

```
public int countSentencesStartingWithUppercase(String line) {
    String regexp = "^[A-Z]|\\. *[A-Z]"; // Note the additional \ this is 
                                         // done because \ is a special 
                                         // character in strings

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
 }
```

[Here a link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to the tutorial on regular expressions in java.

Comment: guess you did the same tiny mistake as i did. the split will still produce the result `2 uppercase sentences` for `sentence 1. Sentence 2`, as the split on the second will still create 2 array elements.

Comment: @KevinEsche thanks for the tip. I edited my answer to retrieve the exact number of matched regular expressions, instead of splitting the string in an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
  String str ="I like Cats. Hey.";
  //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  //System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
  String[] strs = str.split("[.][ ]");
  int count =0;
  for(String string : strs){
      if(Character.isUpperCase( str.charAt(0) )){
          count++;
      }
  }
  System.out.println("the count :"+count);
```

Comment: That will not work. Your code counts **all** uppercase letters in that sentence!

Comment: @KiranKumar did you execute this at least once? it does, because you split each word and not each sentence

Comment: Just a word of advice: if someone asks for help with a problem posting corrected code might help him solve that problem but might not help him learn something or understand the solution. So every answer that contains code should at least contain a few words of explanation what was changed/fixed and why.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right!, I will do it in my all future posts.